# Cannot load model with gensim FastText

Tags: python, numpy, gensim

I`ve faced with trouble to load model using gensim.model.FastText.load().

Here is some code and error which I get:

```
from gensim.models import FastText

class FastTextModel:
    def __init__(self, model_path, dim=300):
        self.dim = dim
        self.model = FastText.load(model_path).wv

...

class GeneralModel:
    def __init__(self, config):
        if config["type"] == "fasttext":
            # path - path to model
            # dim -  dimension, here 300
            self.model = FastTextModel(config["path"], config["dim"])
```

```
  File "/project/preprocessing/pipeline.py", line 15, in __init__
    self.model_ru = GeneralModel(config["models"]["ru"])
  File "/project/models/nlp_models.py", line 101, in __init__
    self.model = FastTextModel(config["path"], config["dim"])
  File "/project/models/nlp_models.py", line 16, in __init__
    self.model = FastText.load(model_path).wv
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/fasttext.py", line 936, in load
    model = super(FastText, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 1244, in load
    model = super(BaseWordEmbeddingsModel, cls).load(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/models/base_any2vec.py", line 603, in load
    return super(BaseAny2VecModel, cls).load(fname_or_handle, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 423, in load
    obj._load_specials(fname, mmap, compress, subname)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 453, in _load_specials
    getattr(self, attrib)._load_specials(cfname, mmap, compress, subname)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/gensim/utils.py", line 464, in _load_specials
    val = np.load(subname(fname, attrib), mmap_mode=mmap)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/npyio.py", line 447, in load
    pickle_kwargs=pickle_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/format.py", line 738, in read_array
    array.shape = shape
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 67239904 into shape (445446,300)
```

I've downloaded models from Google Drive folder, and though that it can somehow damage .npy files (as they are quite big), so I've downloaded each file (there 7 files for that model) separately, but this didn`t help me.

Also, I read that sometimes it can be caused because of bad unzipping in the 'load' method, but I'm passing already unzipped files into it, so this also don`t work for me.

Will be grateful for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where did the model(s) originate? The gensim `FastText.load()` method is only for FastText models created & saved from gensim (via its `.save()` method). Such models use a combination of Python-pickling & sibling `.npy` raw-array files (to store large arrays) which must be kept together.

Models saved from Facebook's original FastText implementation are a different format, for which you'd use the `load_facebook_model()` utility function:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_model

If you only need the vectors – as seems to be the case from your immediate use of only the `.wv` property – you can also use the `load_facebook_vectors()` function:

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/fasttext.html#gensim.models.fasttext.load_facebook_vectors

(Also, not sure why you've wrapped the loaded model in your own `FastTextModel` class which allows the caller to specify a dimensionality. You can't change the dimensionality of a loaded model, so it'd make more sense to just read the existing `vector_size` from the model, rather than specify it outside.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @gojomo, it was pretty informative.

I`ve downloaded models with .npy files from a server via sftp (not from Google Drive), and this fixed the problem for me.

Comment: Aha, yes, perhaps initially some supporting files were missing or truncated by an interrupted download, giving rise to the original `ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 67239904 into shape (445446,300)`. Glad it's working now!